# clearRect() not working in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wrote a function whose purpose is to re-draw a square line block (which cover whole page) every time when the window size is changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/9hVnZ/

The problem is that

```
bgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, bgCtx.width, bgCtx.height);
```

didn't work for me: As my Chrome browser size changed, the previous red lines does not clear as I thought.

reproduced screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSYvT.png

I tried browse other answered questions, some of their cases are missing `bgCtx.beginPath();` but I did include it, and`bgCtx.width = bgCtx.width;` doesn't work, either, am I missing something or anything wrong?

Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new canvas element on every `draw()`.
<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hVnZ/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you!! I focused on the `clearRect()` for a lot time and doesn't notice that!!